# Albania Travel Query

Tags: indian-citizens, hand-luggage, visas-on-arrival, albania

Can Indian Passport holders travel to Albania without a visa?

and what is the best routing from India to Tirana with hand-carry baggage in the last week of October?

Comment: According to https://www.passportindex.org/passport/india/ visa free entry for 90 days is possible for Indian passport holders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the travel date is between 20 April 2022 and 31 December 2022, you can travel.
Wikipedia link - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Albania

(I am not able to find an authoritative source. The [timatic](https://skyteam.traveldoc.aero/) also says you are allowed to travel.)

There are flights from major airports in India that connects via Frankfurt or Dubai. You can look it up in google flights.